# 'iwlist wlan0 bitrate' says "unknown bit-rate information"

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, bitrate

I set bit-rate of wireless interface 'wlan0' using

```
iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M fixed
```

Now, how do I verify if it was set right?

> iwlist wlan0 bitrate

says

> unknown bit-rate information

Answer (score 1):

From the [iwconfig man](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iwconfig8.html) page; emphasis added:

> rate/bit[rate]
>
> *For  cards  supporting  multiple  bit rates, set the bit-rate in
>    b/s.* The bit-rate is the speed at  which  bits  are  transmitted
>    over  the  medium,  the  user  speed of the link is lower due to
>    medium sharing and various overhead.

Not all NICs/drivers can support setting bitrate via iwconfig, and will operate at their default speed for the negotiated connection regardless of whatever iwconfig has to say about it.

Also, the man page says little about the 'fixed' token, but it looks like you want to use 'auto' instead of 'fixed'.

Comment: "You may append the suffix k, M or G to the value (decimal multi-
              plier  :  10^3,  10^6  and  10^9 b/s), or add enough ’0’." follows the text quoted above.



"Not all NICs/drivers can support setting bitrate via iwconfig, and will operate at their default speed for the negotiated connection regardless of whatever iwconfig has to say about it. " -- This is dangerous in my case. I need to put my interface in each of the 802.11a, 802.11b and 802.11g modes for some tests. How do I overcome this?

Comment: if the issue is variable speed control, then you need a new NIC. try dropping the fixed token first.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. 'iwlist'/'iwconfig' and similar tools can display bit-rate of an interface only when it is connected. When the interface is not connected(transmitting), there's no way to determine the rate.

If the interest is in 'how to adjust these bitrates correctly', one may look at:
[this answer at 'Unix StackExchange'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182520/disable-rate-control-in-linux-wireless-driver/182716#182716)